# CV axle problems on my 11' Chevy Impala

Tags: chevrolet, impala, cv-axle

I notice I was having a problem with my car I believe it was the wheel bearing while changing the wheel bearing I noticed it was the CV axle had a little problems getting the axle out didn't have the tools but after I got the tools I got the axle out. After replacement of the new CV Axle the car now rolls unless parking brake is on. Did I do something wrong if so what or what do I need to do to get it fixed

Comment: I'm assuming this is an automatic?